# CSS: last-child selector won't work?

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
<div class="commentList">
    <article class="comment " id="com21"></article>
    <article class="comment " id="com20"></article>
    <article class="comment " id="com19"></article>
</div>
```

Any idea why the following last-child selector won't work for me?

```
.comment {
    width:470px;
    border-bottom:1px dotted #f0f0f0;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.comment:last-child {
    border-bottom:none;
    margin-bottom:0;
}
```

So in this case `#com19` shouldn't have a border and a margin at the bottom.
What am I doing wrong here?

thank you

Comment: I have FF6 and it's working properly (after changing $border to a valid color). What browser do you use? Which version?

Comment: sorry, something didn't work with posting this question. I edited it and now you can see the markup.

Comment: Works for me. I don't see a third border beneath the last child. http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/C23g6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like everything is correct - i have created [jsfiddle with last-child](http://jsfiddle.net/BGND2/)

The problem is somewhere else - what is the value of "$border" ? (is it php variable?)
To be sure that your statements will be used, you can add !important

Comment: oh sorry, the $border variable comes from SASS (allows me to use variables in css. That's not the problem. I updated my question with the markup.

Comment: @mathiregister did you add !important? like .comment:last-child{margin-bottom: 0px !important; }

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you using?

**IE<9** will not apply the `:last-child` selector styles.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate it in Codepen and had a similar Issue. https://codepen.io/Ukmasmu/pen/PoZOLNz

```
    <div class="commentList">
    <article class="comment " id="com21">
      a
    </article>
    <article class="comment " id="com20">
      b
    </article>
       <article class="comment " id="com19">
         c
       </article>
    <script></script>
    </div>
```

Probably there is an invisible element at the end. It seems that it may be an Element like a script tag or some other NodeElement that's not visible. Check the DevTools for that possibility.

You could use the *:last-of-type* pseudo element to be safe!